# Default document root and root directory

Tags: apache2

I don't understand how, on Apache 2.4 running on Linux, a clean Apache installation can disable the access to / and, at the same time, give access to the default document root directory.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I presume that / and the default document root directory are the same directory.

Is / different from the default document root directory? Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Type `ls /var/www/html`, then type `ls /`.  do they look different to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Directory />
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Since "/" is the "root" directory this directive applies to ALL locations.
But the other directive overwrites it and applies to all paths starting with "/var/www/html"

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So in short both directives allow access only below "/var/www/html" but on other locations access is denied.